# Another integral equation question

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that $z = \int_{- \infty}^z f (y) d y$. If $f$ were continuous, we can differentiate both sides to get $f(y)=1$. But what if $f$ does not have to be continuous, is this still true or are there other weird solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the fact that Lebesgue integration extends Riemann integration and the Radon-Nikodym theorem, the Radon-Nikodym deritivative is unique up to a set of measure 0, i.e. $f=1$ except on a set of measure 0. This gives us a way to look for solutions, namely $f=1$ except for $\{0\}$ works.

But I'm not sure whether the Radon-Nikodym deritivative extends the Riemann derivative, can someone post a more general answer if this is not the case?